# Replacing Subqueries with Joins in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have the following query:

```
SELECT PKID, QuestionText, Type 
FROM Questions 
WHERE PKID IN (
    SELECT FirstQuestion 
    FROM Batch 
    WHERE BatchNumber IN (
        SELECT BatchNumber 
        FROM User 
        WHERE RandomString = '$key'
    )
)
```

I've heard that sub-queries are inefficient and that joins are preferred. I can't find anything explaining how to convert a 3+ tier sub-query to join notation, however, and can't get my head around it.

Can anyone explain how to do it?

Comment: well if you post your table structure it will be good

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.*
FROM    Questions a
        INNER JOIN Batch b
            ON a.PKID = b.FirstQuestion
        INNER JOIN User c
            ON b.BatchNumber = c.BatchNumber
WHERE   c.RandomString = '$key'
```

The reason why `DISTINCT` was specified is because there might be rows that matches to multiple rows on the other tables causing duplicate record on the result. But since you are only interested on records on table `Questions`, a `DISTINCT` keyword will suffice.

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: Thank you JW. This has worked a treat. I will just say that I changed `a.*` to `a.PKID, a.QuestionText, a.Type` :)

Comment: It's been a long day and my head is absolutely gone, but this saved me from a lot of despair

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
SELECT q.PKID, q.QuestionText, q.Type 
FROM Questions q
INNER JOIN Batch b ON q.PKID = b.FirstQuestion
INNER JOIN User u ON u.BatchNumber = q.BatchNumber
WHERE u.RandomString = '$key'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    q.pkid,
    q.questiontext,
    q.type
from user u
join batch b
    on u.batchnumber = b.batchnumber
join questions q
    on b.firstquestion = q.pkid
where u.randomstring = '$key'
```

Since your `WHERE` clause filters on the `USER` table, start with that in the `FROM` clause.  Next, apply your joins backwards.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this correctly, you need `distinct` in the subquery.  Otherwise, you might multiply rows in the join version:

```
SELECT q.PKID, q.QuestionText, q.Type 
FROM Questions q join
     (select distinct FirstQuestion
      from Batch b join user u
           on b.batchnumber = u.batchnumber and
              u.RandomString = '$key'
     ) fq
     on q.pkid = fq.FirstQuestion
```

As to whether the `in` or `join` version is better . . . that depends.  In some cases, particularly if the fields are indexed, the `in` version might be fine.